# Manga in which the protagonist can enter stories

Tags: kingdom-hearts

The protagonist enters a story and becomes the replacement for the original protagonist of that story. After each arc, he uses an element of a previous story in order to solve the current story's world's problems. It's still quite new so it should be under 50 chapters.

I read it maybe a half a year ago. Does anyone what manga this might be?

Comment: Do you have an approximate time-frame for "it's still quite new"?

Comment: Maybe half a year ago?

Comment: This question as it stands sounds a bit too broad and a bit unclear what your asking and I might even vote to close. Do you have any idea what genre it might be, when you watched it etc? :)

Comment: @user148900- Please consider editing that into your question and also adding additional details if you can remember. :)

Comment: I think it's either "lasboss x hero" or "Ore ga Heroine o Tasukesugite Sekai ga Little"

Answer (score 3):

It could be [KINGDOM HEARTS](http://myanimelist.net/manga/396/Kingdom_Hearts), and is actually based on a [PlayStation 2 game](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/516587-kingdom-hearts) that came out first.

In the main story, Sora (the protagonist) travels among other worlds. And in each world, he transforms and blends in to resemble the world's characters.
Also in every world, there is a problem that only he could help to fix.

In the first season of this series, there are 43 chapters

[image]